# SQL Multi Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to do a pivot table to show order data by dayofyear.  My first problem is my pivot doesn't appear to be showing the correct data.  My second problem is I don't really want to type out a day for all 365 day columns.  Is there an easier way?

Columns would be 1 - 365

Rows would be Year, #orders, #Tags

```
SELECT Yr, [01],[02],[03],[04],[05]....
FROM (
select TOP 100 PERCENT 
YEAR(tagdata.shipdate) AS Yr,
DATEPART(dy,tagdata.shipdate) AS Day,
tagdata.#Orders,
tagdata.#Tags,
from tagData 
GROUP BY tagData.ShipDate, tagdata.#Orders, tagdata.#Tags
) AS sourcetable
PIVOT
( 
Max(#Orders) FOR Day IN ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],.......),
Max(#Tags) FOR Day IN ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],.......)
)
as pivottable
ORDER BY Yr
```

Comment: I would think about doing this as a crosstab instead of a pivot. This is also referred to a "conditional aggregate". There are hundreds of examples on SO and everywhere around the internet. I would also suggest dropping the top 100 percent as it is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two pivots for each set of fields you are looking at and then join them on the year.  Something like this:

```
SELECT isnull(pivottable1.Yr, pivottable2.Yr) Yr,
    [1ORD],[2ORD],[3ORD],[4ORD],[5ORD],
    [1TAG],[2TAG],[3TAG],[4TAG],[5TAG]
FROM (
    select TOP 100 PERCENT 
    YEAR(shipdate) AS Yr,
    Convert(varchar(3),DATEPART(dy,shipdate)) + 'ORD' AS Day,
        #Orders
    from #tagData 
    ) AS sourcetable1
PIVOT
    ( 
    Max(#Orders) FOR Day IN ([1ORD],[2ORD],[3ORD],[4ORD],[5ORD])
    ) as pivottable1
full join (
    select TOP 100 PERCENT 
    YEAR(shipdate) AS Yr,
    Convert(varchar(3),DATEPART(dy,shipdate)) + 'TAG' AS Day,
        #Tags
    from #tagData 
    ) AS sourcetable2
PIVOT
    ( 
    Max(#Tags) FOR Day IN ([1TAG],[2TAG],[3TAG],[4TAG],[5TAG])
    ) as pivottable2
on pivottable1.Yr = pivottable2.Yr
ORDER BY isnull(pivottable1.Yr, pivottable2.Yr)
```

As for all that typing... a simple script can cover you:

```
declare @number as int
declare @numbers as varchar(max)
set @number=1
while @number <= 365
begin
    set @numbers = isnull(@numbers+',','') + '[' + convert(varchar(3),@number) + ']'
    set @number=@number+1
end
print @numbers
```